# Get users from a group

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, accounts

I want to get the users of a group separately for each existing group in `/etc/group`

I have the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash

while IFS=: read user pass uid users
do
echo -e "$full :\n\
    Pseudo : $user\n\
    UID :\t $uid\n\
    Users :\t $users\n\\n"

done < /etc/group
```

With this script I get all the users separated by `,` but I need them separately to modify the groups to which a user belongs with `usermod -a -g group user`

Comment: You are going to do what? You need a list of all groups and their users, and then you're going to add users to groups, using what criteria?  If you know what users _should be_ in a group, just go through those users and add them to that group. To do this, you don't need to loop through the `/etc/group` file.

Comment: What about users who have that group as their primary group?

Comment: I want to export the users and groups that I have in an old server to a new one. As several groups I want to do it faster using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the items in a comma-separated list with:

```
IFS=, for user in $users
do
    ...
done
```

`IFS` is the field separator that's used to split a variable expansion into words, so this tells it to use `,` as the delimiter instead of spaces.